# Command for viewing overall git status regardless of location in directory

Tags: git, bash, command-line, directory-structure, git-stash

Is there a way to see a big-picture status in git? I'm new to git and end up losing files based on stashing them in the wrong directory or working on the wrong branch, and I'd like to find a command that gives me an overview of everything, regardless of where in the directory I am or which branch I currently have checked out. Does that exist? (I'm using bash)

Comment: Start small, with a toy repo, some bigger than a helloworld project. Get used to how things work.  Follow the tutorials in the doc slavishly, then once more with feeling. Again with the toy project but beat things up, ruin the thing, try random commands just to see what breaks, repeat.  You'll find the overview commands and know when to use them.

Answer (score 1):

- Show all **commits**: `git log --all` (try `--graph` and `--decorate` for more info)
- Show **commits which have at some time been at the head of the current branch** (useful for restoring deleted or rebased-beyond-recognition commits): `git reflog`
- Show all **branches** with their latest commit hash and first line of commit message:`git branch --verbose`
- Show all **remotes**: `git remote --verbose`

Answer (score 1):

Try with the default frontends of git

- gitk : Frontend to see your history of commits. Similar to git log.
- git GUI : Frontend to do commits, pushes, add remotes, prune.

Answer (score 0):

Also some Git Client like [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) is very useful to see what is going on.

Friendly but will hide the most of the git commands from you. So a good combo can be use terminal to do things and in case of confusion or conflicts you can get some "help" from the Git Client.